# Android: setOnKeyListener on EditText

Tags: android, android-view

I have a EditText on my View and I would like to set a onKeyListener.

Here is my code:

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            return false;
        }
    });   
}
```

The problem is that i have problems with this, here is a error part of the logcat:

```
W/dalvikvm(3703): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3703): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{milos.mdpi/milos.mdpi.MDPIActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at milos.mdpi.MDPIActivity.<init>(MDPIActivity.java:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
E/AndroidRuntime(3703):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: you get NPE because `findViewById()` returns null, since you call it before content view is set, so `edittext` is null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private EditText edittext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.<yourlayout>.xml);
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

if the problem persists, and you still get NPE, your EditText probably have other id in your layout xml.

Comment: Great Vladimir, the problem was that i had more than 1 xml files and the view where was the Edittext was not main.

Answer (score 2):

u need to write

after setting ContentView `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

in `onCreate()` and not out of `onCreate();`.

Comment: +1, i just want to add `findViewById(R.id.editText1);` should be called after `setContentView()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Riche, This is not resolving my problem... I have still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

setContentView(R.layout.main);  is missing

Comment: Thank you, even if i use the setContentView(R.layout.main), i am still having the same error.

Comment: Check out the beginning of this tutorial, there must be sg you miss: http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/